# How can I erase the Author of the blog posts from showing on the Homepage's H2 tags?

Tags: php, wordpress, vcf-vcard, author

I have had a helluva time trying to find the H2 tag code that pulls up on the homepage of the site that I am optimizing.

http://tinyurl.com/cynvmka

I am guessing that the H2 code of the DATE + AUTHOR is hard-coded somewhere where I'm not looking.

Would someone please lend a hand on where I can find the code that pulls up the H2 tag? I would like to keep the calendar date, only want to remove the author.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use `firebug` for firefox or any other dev tool for other browser to see what html tag with a name and id attributes  displays it

And then create a css that would hide it like

```
.title_and_date{
  display:none;
}
```

or if you want this to be done backend of wp find

```
<?php the_author() ?>
<?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
```

because thats makes you post the author and date

---

try to add this in your css i check your link and see which html tags it falls

```
 footer.entry-meta{
       display:none;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to work it by doing this: .by-author {
  display: none;
}
Thank you for your tip! It lead me in the right path!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.knocksteady.com/wp-content/themes/KSV3/style.css

in style.css line no-993
and add this

footer.entry-meta {
    color: #757575;
    display: none;
    font-size: 0.928571rem;
    line-height: 1.84615;
    margin-top: 0;
}